# Property cmis:parentId is only defined for folders

Tags: apache, repository, cmis

I'm writing a CMIS interface for my application. This interface returns a `cmis:document` object as a child of a `cmis:folder` object. Here is [a part of xml output](http://pastebin.com/Ta6QEHLN).

The `cmis:document` object has a `cmis:parentId` property. Now I'd like to validate the `cmis:document` object with the [Apache Chemistry Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html).
The workbench tool tells me:

> Property `cmis:parentId` is only defined for folders.

Why is this property not allowed for a document? How can a document reference its parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `cmis:parentId` is [not defined for `cmis:document` objects](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cs01/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905396) because a document can have none, one or multiple parents.

To get the parents of a document [you have to call `getObjectParents()`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cs01/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905446).

You can, of course, deliver the parent id(s) in another property that doesn't use the reserved namespace `cmis:`, but that would be repository specific and generic CMIS clients would ignore it.